# Python ( Heads or Tails Counter )

Tags: python, random

I'm trying to create a simple heads or tails program. For some reason it's not working and I have no idea why. Any ideas?

```
import random


counter = 0
flip = random.randint(1,2) # Initializing Values of variables
heads_counter = 0
tails_counter = 0

if flip == 1:
    heads_counter +=1
    counter +=1

elif flip == 2:
     tails_counter +=1
     counter +=1

else:
    print("Invalid flip")


print("Flip is",flip)
print("Flipped The coin",counter,"Times")
print("Landed Heads",heads_counter,"Times")
print("Landed Tails",tails_counter,"Times")
```

Comment: [Seems to be working for me](http://repl.it/BAMo)

Comment: Seems to work for me. whats the error?

Comment: are you sure you only want one coin flip? it looks like you prepared to do several coin tosses; i.e. put your logic inside a loop.

Comment: Please explain - *it's not working* . We need more info , than just a dump of your code.

Comment: You mean, you're running `python yourprogram.py` several times and  not seeing landed head or landed tails incrementing? That is normal behaviour.

Comment: Sorry I should add that i am expecting the coin too flip 100 times

Comment: i did try putting it within this loop         while counter < 100:                                              but it just flipped it once and then multiplied it by 100 so it would just say either heads 100 or tails 100 ?

Comment: I think if you moved the `flip` assignment inside of your while loop it would have worked how you expected it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the numbers to increment, you must have multiple flips during one execution. Here is a much simpler implementation of what you are doing that runs the program `num` times.

To flip the coin 100 times, simply set `num = 100`

```
from random import randint

# number of coin flips to simulate
num = 100

# simulate the coin flips
flips = [randint(1,2) for x in range(num)]

# count up the results
heads = flips.count(1)
tails = flips.count(2)

# print the results to the console
print("{0} Coin Flips".format(num))
print("{0} Heads".format(heads))
print("{0} Tails".format(tails))
```

This gives you output like the following:

```
>>> 100 Coin Flips
>>> 49 Heads
>>> 51 Tails
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dude, So much more efficient and simple.... sigh i got a long way to go